# Webpack angular2 doc polyfills.ts zone require instead of import

Tags: angular, webpack, zone

I'm taking a look at

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

and in the `src/polyfills.ts` (right above [*Highlights*](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html#!#highlights-)) I can see

```
import 'core-js/es6';
import 'reflect-metadata';
require('zone.js/dist/zone');
```

Does anyone explain me why for zone is using `require()` instead of `import`?

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the "(right above Highlights)" part (to make it easier for people to find what you are referring to). If you don't think that is accurate, please edit it out.

Comment: About the case, I can't tell (thus the comment, not answer), but if that's not a mistake (I mean, it *could*  be like that just by accident, meaning both ways are interchangeable), then the possible difference is that `import` will probably go through (and gets changed by) the TS loader and `require()` doesn't. So if the TS loader processes it, you have to configure it to find those imports, something you wouldn't need to do when using `require()`. Anyway, would have to set up what they suggest at that guide to test, so this is just guessing...

Comment: @acdcjunior dont worry about it well done